# R filter a dataframe based on fuzzy match with list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, match

given dataframe :

```
df = data.frame(
    el = c('one1', 'one2', 'two', 'three', 'four1', 'four2' )
)
```

how to filter based on the following list

```
keeps = c('one', 'two', 'four')
```

such that the rows

```
'one1', 'one2', 'two', 'four1', 'four2'
```

would be returned.

Basicially I would like to be able to index a dataframe based on a list, but
with a fuzzy match rather than an exact match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of options. My favorite is filter from `dplyr` along with grepl

```
df %>% 
  filter(.,grepl('one|two|four',el)) #Matches anything containing one,two,or four

     el
1  one1
2  one2
3   two
4 four1
5 four2

df %>% 
  filter(.,grepl('one|two',el))

    el
1 one1
2 one2
3  two
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use

```
 with(df,subset(df,grepl(paste0(keeps,collapse = "|"),el)))
```

which gives

```
     el
1  one1
2  one2
3   two
5 four1
6 four2
```